# Debugging an access violation

Tags: c++, debugging, access-violation

I'm using a large closed-source framework. I recently added a new entity, and now I'm getting access violations when performing some actions. However, they occur on calls from within the framework, so I don't know what I've implemented wrong, since I don't get a call stack.

The violation is reported in the function `_CRTIMP PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION __cdecl __set_flsgetvalue()` defined in the CRT file `tidtable.c`. The specific row is `PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION flsGetValue = FLS_GETVALUE;`. I'm not sure, but I think it is related to function pointers?

The error message is `Unhandled exception at 0x0000007a in fmwk.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000007a.`. My interpretation is that it's attempting to access something at offset `0x7a` into an object, but it's acually given a null pointer. Is this correct? If it is, is there a way of finding what that offset corresponds to?

Below is the call stack:

```
0000007a()  
fmwk.dll!100f2630()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for fmwk.dll]  

<lots of framework and windows dlls>

fmwk.exe!00402ef4()     
msvcr100.dll!__set_flsgetvalue()  Line 145 + 0xc bytes  C
msvcr100.dll!_getptd_noexit()  Line 498 + 0x7 bytes C
msvcr100.dll!_getptd()  Line 523 + 0x5 bytes    C
msvcr100.dll!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
msvcr100.dll!x_ismbbtype_l(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, unsigned int tst=0, int cmask=1386664, int kmask=1414714)  Line 219 C++
msvcr100.dll!_ismbblead(unsigned int tst=0)  Line 172 + 0xe bytes   C++
fmwk.exe!004010a0()     
fmwk.exe!00404d61()     
kernel32.dll!7c817077()
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a [run-time library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) mismatch given that it looks like the code is trying to access non-existent thread local storage (though I might be misreading the stack trace wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Application Verifier to debug this access violation. It should stop execution earlier when bad thing happens with better call stack than this one.

Looks like you dereferenced NULL pointer somewhere but program did not crash immediately since it is Undefined Behaviour, continued executing and crashed a bit later with weird call stack.

Comment: It seems like a nice program, thanks for the tip. However, either I don't understand it, or it cannot help me. It triggers a break, but the call stack doesn't help here either. The only examinable frames are from Application Verifier itself, and the data availible is just an error message "first chance access violation for current stack trace".

Comment: You have to load debug symbols of close-source framework to get helpful call stack. Do you have them?

Comment: Nope. And I seriously doubt I will be able to get them either :(

Comment: I'll accept this, not because it solved my problem, but because it should have :) (I could not get anywhere with the problem, and it was decided to chuck it out and use another class)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question: Yes, accessing 0x7A suspiciously looks like dereferencing a NULL pointer at offset 0x7a. (Could also be something like dereferencing 0x20 with offset 0x5a though).

Without source code access it is hard to find out what's going on. You could try backtracking with your code and figure out which change you made that made the framework to bail out. Then, see if you are using a framework function different from how it is supposed to be used. If this all seems to lead to no end, you could also report a bug to your framework vendor, but I'd advise you to make sure the fault is not on your side before you do that.

Comment: Oh I'm pretty sure the fault is mine. Adding new functionality requires quite a lot of code, and it is all added at once. I've re-read all my code a few times and can't spot any errors, but I'm guessing I missed initializing some function pointer member which is inherited (the framework has it's own class emulation, written in C).